# Corda: Unable to upload attachment to Corda node

Tags: corda

I am unable to upload attachment to a Corda node using the following javascript code. I get "HTTP ERROR 400 Problem accessing /upload/attachment. Reason: Got an upload request with no files".

```
uploadmodalInstance.attachmentfile = document.getElementById('attachmentfile').files[0];

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('jar', uploadmodalInstance.attachmentfile);

$http.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';

// NOW UPLOAD THE FILES.
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/upload/attachment',
    data: formdata,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryqtDm9u9ZQbwnwy3A'}
}).then(
    (result) => {
        uploadmodalInstance.displayMessage(result); //success
    },
    (result) => {
        uploadmodalInstance.displayMessage(result); //failure
    }
);
```

However, I am able to upload the same attachment using HTML like below:

```
<form action="http://localhost:10007/upload/attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="jar" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload blacklist</button>
 </form>
```

What is the problem with javascript? I checked headers and formdata in Firefox developer tools, it is identical in both cases.

Here's the HTML page code containing attachmentfile element:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="demoAppUploadModal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Upload a Document</h4>
        </div>
        <form>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="attachmentfile" class="control-label">Document Attachment:</label>
                    <input type="file" ng-model="uploadmodalInstance.form.attachmentfile" class="form-control" id="attachmentfile">
                </div>

                <div ng-show="modalInstance.formError" class="form-group">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                        Enter valid parameters
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button ng-click="uploadmodalInstance.cancel()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button ng-click="uploadmodalInstance.create()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--form action="/upload/attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="jar" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload Document</button>
        </form -->
</script>
```

Comment: So I can replicate, can you show how you put the `attachmentfile` element on the page?

Comment: I have now included HTML code containing the "attachmentfile" element in my post.

Answer (score 0):

So just try to remember that attachments work differently in the new version of Corda.

I'll quote the docs here on an answer for how to use corda attachments.

> To add attachments the file must first be uploaded to the node, which returns a unique ID that can be added using TransactionBuilder.addAttachment(). Attachments can be uploaded and downloaded via RPC and the Corda Node shell.

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-attachments.html